# Running Page Load multiple times

Tags: c#, events, user-controls, postback

I have a user control on an aspx page that contains filter fields and return a WhereClause.  The user conrol will raise an event called FilterApplied when Search is clicked.

On my main form, I add the control with:

> ```
> <uc1:Filter runat="server" ID="Filter" />
> <br />
> ```

In my code behind I have:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Register event when filter is changed.
        this.Filter.FilterApplied += new EventHandler(this.FilterApplied);

        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        { //Do some things that take long 
        }
     }

    protected void FilterApplied(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Reload the page to refresh the graphs.
        Page_Load(sender, e);
    }
```

Problem is:
When I click Search on my user control, the Form_Load runs twice.  Once because it is reloaded and then another time because I call it from FilterApplied.  If I don't call it from FilterApplied, then the whereclause is still empty.

How can I ensure the Page_Load only run once when Search is clicked?

Comment: Then don't call `Page_Load` from your `FilterApplied` method.

Comment: Not working. "If I don't call it from FilterApplied, then the whereclause is still empty."

Comment: Why is the question unclear or not useful (or show a lack of research effort?  If it's unclear I can try and correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lays in multiple registering for FilterApplied event. Each time you call the Page_Load method, you subscribe to this event again. Here is a really simple example of what you are doing, written in WinForms with one button on the form, just to point out your problem:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int numClicks = 0;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
        this.Text = numClicks.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numClicks++;
        //try uncommenting and commenting next line of code, and observe the difference:
        //button1.Click -= button1_Click;
        Form1_Load(sender, e);
    }

}
```

Comment: I can see - thanks.  But if I uncomment the line as suggested, the Load event still runs twice, so I'm not 100% sure ow to fix my part, as the first time the Load event occurs the whereClause property of the control has not been set yet.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Move the numClicks++ line to the last line of Form1_Load, and you'll see that it is incremented by one, if you uncomment button1.Click -= button1_Click; line in button1_Click method.  You can also set breakpoint anywhere in Form1_Load method, and see for your self that it will be hit only once.

Comment: Seems like mine is working differently.  Just to confirm: If I run your code as is, the caption of the form goes up exponentially.  That makes sense.  But if I uncomment the line (or move the line of code as suggested), then the form caption goes up my an increment of 2. Is that correct?  Adding breakpoints shows me that the Form1_Load  is executed twice.

Comment: That indicates that you are actually subscribing to click event twice. You probably did it once in the Form design mode, on button -> properties -> events, and then again in Form_Load method. Remove one of them, and that is probably the case with your user control.

Comment: Ahh, that's better.  Thanks.